# Add fixed footer button in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I used CoordinatorLayout for the below code, here I need to add a fixed footer button, I was tried but while scrolling the button also getting scroll to top.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/base_five_dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvProperties"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_visit_details" />

        <include layout="@layout/layout_tool_bar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to put the button outside the `AppBarLayout` and inside the `CoordinatorLayout`, like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/base_five_dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvProperties"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_visit_details" />

        <include layout="@layout/layout_tool_bar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<Button
    android:text="CIAOO"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I think this should work

Like this it's showing

[image]

Comment: Try to give android:layout_height="wrap_content" to your CardView element

Comment: the button behind to RecyclerView

Comment: Try to give android:layout_height="wrap_content" to your CardView element and to RecyclerView inside

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you saying: "if the recyclerview inside the cardview is filled of elements, is the button still displayed?" - the answer to this question is: Yes. Ah, don't forget to accept the best answer, thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, actually my question is during run time if the RecyclerView inside the CardView is filled of elements, at that time the button will go behind to RecylerView or still it will display?

Comment: When the RecylcerView is filled with elements, you won't be able to see the last item(s) because the bottom view will overlap them. Consider to set bottom padding to the RecyclerView with the same value as button height.

Comment: main thing is android:layout_gravity="bottom" in this case.  and we can also use android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" to display button at right corner of screen etc..

Comment: this has problems with appbarlayout, doesnt work

Answer (score 3):

you need to just add a layout before closing your coordinator layout tag!

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_bottom">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/base_five_dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvProperties"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                 <include layout="@layout/layout_visit_details" />

                 <include layout="@layout/layout_tool_bar" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#FF6D00"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="BUTTON" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Button came but AppBarLayout is going behind to RecyclerView. So the AppBarLayout is not displaying